# Characteristic impedance equivalent cirucit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transmission-line, equivalent-circuit

As far as I've understood, the characteristic impedance Z0 of a transmission line corresponds to the equivalent impedance of the line when it's not connected to any load. If one would like to represent the equivalent circuit of the transmission line using the characteristic impedance, should Z0 be in series/parallel to the input V? Let's consider the most general case where Z0 is complex please.

Comment: No, your initial sentence is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the characteristic impedance corresponds to the equivalent impedance of the line when it is infinitely long.  It doesn't matter after an infinity of transmission line whether you'll leave it open or shortcircuited or closed off properly: the end is too far away to interact with the beginning in any finite amount of time anyway.

Closing off a *finite* piece of line with the line impedance thus is indistinguishable for that finite piece of line from closing it off with an infinite stretch of more line.  So there is no reason for the transition from finite piece of line to line impedance termination to cause a reflection, because obviously an infinite stretch of ongoing line is no cause for reflection either and is electrically indistinguishable from the line impedance termination.

So with regard to Z0 and "input V": the line needs to see Z0.  How that Z0 is decomposed into what you call "input" and other circuits does not matter.  For the old coaxial Ethernet cables, taps were current sources (infinite impedance) and did not disturb the waves travelling the cable.  And at both ends, you attached terminators providing the full Z0.

When using video opamps or similar, you'll have to check their output impedance at the given gain and then add circuitry making up for the totality of Z0.  Whether this circuitry is in parallel or in series or both does not matter: the end result needs to expose Z0 to the transmission line start.